# SpaceClaim 2014 export to STEP don't work

Tags: export, cad, step, stp

I want to export my project from SpaceClaim2014 to STEP file but i dont know how - i try simply to save file as but there is no option to save file as .step or .stp file and when I tried to put .step in filename it resulted with output file like myproject.step.scdoc, or another time myproject.step.jpg, there is no way I can export my project with 3D geometry to other CAD solutions but I SpaceClaim is not enough for me and moving to another program I dont want to miss my complex and big project which costed a lot of work.

Comment: have you tried to use the export function? The SpaceClaim claims that it can export parts and assemblies as STEP 203 and 214 files.